# PHP - is it recommended to use mysqli_data_seek within a loop

Tags: mysqli, database-performance

When looping through a `mysqli` query the usual way would be:

```
$res = $db->query($sql);
while($rs = $res->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo $rs['field'];
}
```

I found out that I could use `mysqli_data_seek` for setting the internal result pointer, so I could change the loop into the following:

```
$res = $db->query($sql);
$records = $res->num_rows;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $records-1; $i++)
{
    mysqli_data_seek($res,$i); // set result pointer 
    $rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    echo $rs['field'];
}
```

I benchmarked both ways and couldn't see any difference but I was wondering - are there any drawbacks using the second method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> PHP - is it recommended to use mysqli_data_seek within a loop

of course not.

> are there any drawbacks using the second method?

Sure. It takes as much as twice more code than first one.